# mysql-Unhandled Exception at 0x51f99754 in namer.exe:0xC000005:Access Violation in reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I am using mysql C APIs in my c++ program for updating a remote DB and parsing a select query which returns the number of rows.

Here is my code:

```
MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

 if (con == NULL) 
 {
 AfxMessageBox("Could not initialize SQL Connection");
 return;
 }  

 if (mysql_real_connect(con, LINK, UID, PASSWORD, NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) 
 {
 AfxMessageBox("Could not connect to MySQL Server");
 return;
 }
 sprintf(uquery, "UPDATE test SET `emailid` = '%s', `name` = '%s' WHERE `ID` IS NULL;", eID, name);

 mysql_query(con, uquery);

 sprintf(squery,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE `emailID` = '%s' AND `ID` IS NOT NULL", key, emailID);

 mysql_query(con,squery);

 MYSQL_RES *res = mysql_store_result(con);

 if((int)mysql_num_rows(res) != NULL)//<--ERROR SHOWS HERE
 {
  int rows = mysql_num_rows(res);
  if (rows == 1)
  {
  //Do something
  }
  else
  {
  //Do Something else
  }
 }
 else
 {
  //Some function 3
 }
 mysql_free_result(res);
 mysql_close(con);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Unhandled exception at 0x51f99754 in namer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Please help.

Comment: You don't check neither the return value of `mysql_query(con,squery)`  nor the return value of `mysql_store_result(con)`. You should check both.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a NULL pointer somewhere that the database engine doesn't expect.

Use a debugger to get a backtrace (call stack) - this will show which line in your code is the "guilty culprit".